# ESXi Trunk Load-Balancing with two Switches

Tags: vmware-esxi, load-balancing, trunk

My ESXi hosts are connected to two switches as described [in figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NrPg.png). 
[image]

When i configure the Load-Balancing method of the trunks to "IP-Hash" the virtual hosts are flapping in between the portchannel-groups:

```
21-07-2017 09:00:45     Warning (4)     SW_MATM-4-MACFLAP_NOTIF   Host 0050.5688.1141 in vlan 60 is flapping between port Po1 and port Po3
```

If the trunks are configured to load-balance by src-MAC the virtual host is not flapping anymore. But i don't get the benefits of the IP-Hash load-balancing method.
Does anyone know how great the performance-loss is due to the MAC-flapping?

Backup-Question: Is there a "supported" way to connect two switches to two esxi-hosts (VMware ESXi 6.5) without VDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the second question is simple. No, there is no supported way to connect one ESXi-Host to two Switches: [KB1001938](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1001938):

> - ESXi/ESX host only supports NIC teaming on a single physical switch or stacked switches.
> - VMware supports only one Etherchannel bond per Virtual Standard Switch (vSS).

The first answer is a bit more tricky... It depends... In my tests, the VM was flapping only a few times, so there was absolutley no increase in the cpu usage of the switch. But as described [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-4000-series-switches/65591-cat4500-high-cpu.html), this can be an issue when the mac table alters quickly.

Answer (score 0):

With an ESXi standard vSwitch, don't configure any bonding/trunking on the physical switch(es). Regardless of which load balancing you choose, any connection will only use a specific port. When a link goes down, the vNIC will move according to the failover scheme you configured.

A vSwitch will never resend a frame received on a physical link. This makes spanning tree, trunking/bonding or more elaborate features unnecessary and potentially more harm than benefit.

If you do need more bandwidth for a guest VM, just add more vNICs to it and the load will distribute over all ports and physical switches - depending on the load balancing scheme.

Comment: No bonding/trunking at all? Would not traffic from the physical switch or beyond to the VM never have more bandwidth than a single port?

Comment: It simply works better without. You don't need it and it interferes with controlling the flows. Link bonding only increases the bandwidth for multiple connections anyway, never for a single flow. Do you need to increase ingress or egress bandwidth or both directions (from the VM/host POV)? What does the scenario look like (hosts to physical switches layout; large number of clients, low number of partners, ....)?

Comment: As hinted in [figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NrPg.png) the physical switches are used as routers. Both have an 1G uplink to an ISP.

The VMs on the ESXi hosts are virtual firewalls with a few hundred clients. Therefor it would be great to achieve more than 1G for the overall flows.

Comment: I'd use four (or two) vNICs per VM, attach them to both switches (either with dedicated pNICs (for four) or teamed pNICs (for two) and have the clients attach per round-robin. On the switches, configure ports without bonding. If you use dedicated pNICs, add port groups with a single active NIC and the other one as fail-over and attach each vNIC to one of these port groups. Have you read [this](https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/virtual_networking_concepts.pdf)? Aged, but still a good primer.